# Python で cv2.imshow としても画像が表示されない

Tags: python, opencv

当方初心者です。
http://opencv.blog.jp/python/install_easy を参照し、 python で opencv を使用して画像を表示させようとしましたが、新規ウィンドウがフリーズして表示されません。 pythonxy でも anacondaでも同様です。

コードは

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread("test1")
cv2.imshow("test",img)
```

です。
フリーズ時のメッセージは `init done opengl support available` です。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

「フリーズ」とは違いますが、すぐに終了してしまっているだけかも知れません。
その場合は `waitKey` などを入れる事で解決します。

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('./test.png', 0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```